# How to check if Dark Mode is enabled in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to check if chrome is currently in dark mode to theme my extension accordingly.

I've already checked the chrome api but did not find any suitable option. Maybe there is some trick to find out the status. JavaScript or CSS should be fine.

Comment: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-detect-a-users-preferred-color-scheme-in-javascript-ec8ee514f1ef

Comment: Simply add `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) { /* your dark theme here */ }`

Comment: Chrome 76 https://caniuse.com/prefers-color-scheme

Comment: see also [Toggle Chrome Extension Icon based on light or dark mode browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58880234/toggle-chrome-extension-icon-based-on-light-or-dark-mode-browser)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In CSS (possible values are: `light`, `dark`, `no-preference` [css docs](https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries-5/#descdef-media-prefers-color-scheme)) [works with all modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=prefers-color-scheme):

```css
@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {  
  .themed {  
     background: white;    
     color: black;  
  }
}
```

Follow up with JS ([all modern browsers support this](https://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia)):

```
window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)')
```

[image]

Bonus:

In electron:

```
const { systemPreferences } = require('electron')
console.log(systemPreferences.isDarkMode())
```