# Toggle Chrome Extension Icon based on light or dark mode browser?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've tried searching for this, and the [closest related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36931484/light-dark-browseraction-icons-in-chrome-51) that I could find was from 3+ years ago and had to do with the incognito window being dark, while a normal chrome window was light back then.

Now that we have the ability to have a light or dark mode browser, it's hard to find an icon design and color that looks good for both light and dark modes. Here's an example:

[image: Examples of icons on dark-mode theme]

In the image above you can see that the first and third icons are black, so they are hard to see when using dark-mode. The middle icon (the one I'm using for my extension)looks great on dark mode, but terrible on light mode. See below:

[image: light icons are hard to see unless on dark mode]

So does anyone know if there is there a way to detect the browser mode (light or dark) and swap out the icon?

Comment: Listen to `prefers-color-scheme` media query change event. You'll have to do it in a content script because it won't work in the background script, https://crbug.com/968651. However users may want to switch the icon explicitly to accommodate their custom browser themes so it's best to expose the icon switch option.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not using a content script. Just a background script. But I can call other scripts from the background.js script. When I add this code to background.js it works, but there's no logic to detect light or dark mode, so the icon always changes to green. `chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
   path : {
         "16": "icon16green.png",
   }
});` So are you saying that logic (something lik `window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: light)');`) isn't available from background pages?

Comment: Are you doubting what I'm saying? :-)

Comment: Lol. Not at all. Just not sure if I'm completely understanding it. I'm new to extensions. If there was a way to execute a script from a background script on page load (rather than onClicked) that would work I think. But I don't think that's possible either.

Comment: There's a bug/limitation that requires you to run the detection code in a visible page, not in the background script. So you'll have to use a content script just for this.

Comment: Bummer. Yea, I saw the bug you linked in your first post. Thank you for your help! I'll see if I can figure out a way to use a content script instead, but I feel like there was a reason I couldn't.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Thanks to  [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) I was able to figure this out.

First, I needed to create a content script (which I called `toggleIcon.js`) and add it to the `manifist.json file`.

[image]

Then I added the following to `toggleIcon.js` - which sends `scheme: "dark"` to my background.js file if `window.matchMedia` matches `prefers-color-scheme: dark`.

[image]

Then in my `background.js` file I listen for that message, and if `request.scheme == "dark"` I use `chrome.broserAction.setIcon` to change the paths for each of my icons to the dark version.

[image]

This effectively overrides my original icon paths as declared in the `manifest.json` file (as shown below).

[image]

The only downside I see is that this requires a `content_script`, which if you want your extension to work on any page, requires you to also add `"matches": ["<all_urls>"]` to your extension, which slows down the approval process. Which is why in my comments above I mentioned I had been avoiding using a content_script.

Also, I think it makes sense to use the version of your icons that work best on light-mode as your default, because I think the chrome extension page will pull from these for some of the icons they use (and that page has a white background). As an example, here's how my old icon looked (not enough contrast).

[image]

Hopefully this helps someone else!!

Comment: The code you're running in the content script doesn't actually require a content script. `matchMedia()` works fine in a background script and returns the correct value. The thing that doesn't work in the background is adding a listener to the media match. You'll need to add one in your content script, something like `matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').addListener(({matches}) => chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ scheme: matches ? "dark" : "light" })`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I'm not working on my extension at the moment. But I'll take a look at your suggestions once I get back into the code.

Comment: Manifest v3 doesn't have background scripts. They have been replaced with service workers. You can't access `window` from service workers either.