# Detect dark mode of the Chrome in the extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-theme

I have an extension and I want to detect dark mode in Chrome.

In the `toggleIcon.js` I try to detect theme by this code:

```
if (window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
     scheme: "dark"
  })
}
else{
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    scheme: "light"
  })
}
```

And In the `background.js` I try to get requests with this code:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log(request.scheme)
  sendResponse();
});
```

But I always get light mode even when using [Bits + Pieces](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bits-%20-pieces/foocngohimdoacmhbjfkdldchhiipieo) theme for chrome.
How can I fix my problem?

Comment: @wOxxOm Could you please explain more?

Comment: That theme package is not what constitutes a `dark` theme. Only the dark theme in the OS settings does that. Then it is automatically detected by Chrome.

Comment: see also [Toggle Chrome Extension Icon based on light or dark mode browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58880234/toggle-chrome-extension-icon-based-on-light-or-dark-mode-browser)